# How to use a hash (#) as a delimiter for sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I haven't used `sed` that often and apologies if this question is too simple.

The following works great:

```
sed -i '/<\/IfModule>/i TEST' security2.conf
```

Now I want to use `#` as the delimiter. Why doesn't this work?

```
sed -i '#</IfModule>#i TEST' security2.conf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual page for `sed`(1) writes

> `/regexp/` Match lines matching the regular expression `regexp`.
>
> `\cregexpc` Match lines matching the regular expression `regexp`.  The `c` may be any character.

So you can replace `/regexp/` with `\#regexp#`, or in your specific case:

```
sed -i '\#</IfModule>#i TEST' security2.conf
```

Personally I'd test without `-i` until I was sure I'd got it right.

Comment: Awesome, thank you all! What a rookie mistake. I tried the `|` pipe too, perhaps that has a special meaning in `sed`?

Comment: @Abs the man page says that tf it's not `/` you have to precede it with `\ `. So `\|` would be required rather than just `|`.

Answer (score 3):

Searching for `#` in the manual `sed(1)` one may find

```
 [0addr]#
         The ``#'' and the remainder of the line are ignored (treated as a
         comment), with the single exception that if the first two charac-
         ters in the file are ``#n'', the default output is suppressed.
         This is the same as specifying the -n option on the command line.
```

So you've written a comment which is not code.